# Scala Slick 3 Future class callback pattern matching

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0, playframework-2.5

I have a DAO where I check for a username and want to extend it to check for password as well, but for testing purpose as I am new to this, I am checking only for email. Here is the DAO:

```
def authenticate(username: String, password: String): Future[Option[User]] = {

    db.run(Users.filter(_.email === username).result).map(_.headOption)
  }
```

Now, I have a form with verifying method implemented. I can do onSuccess and onFailue callback, but I am not able to do onComplete.
Currently it is like this:

```
val loginForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "username" -> nonEmptyText,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText
    ) verifying("Wrong username or password!", fields => fields match{
      case (username, password) => {
        val query = userDao.authenticate(username, password)

        query onComplete  {
          case Success(Option[User]) => println("Success")
          case Failure(_) => println("Failed ")
        }

        false
      }
    })
  )
```

So, the Success class is where the problem is, as it says `Pattern type is incompatible with expected type, found: Option.type, required Option[User]`.
Now, how to resolve this error and how could I fetch the result from that select query via slick?
The model is simple with email and password as values.

Thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I do async form validation in Play Framework 2.x (Scala)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913074/can-i-do-async-form-validation-in-play-framework-2-x-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that line to

```
case Success(Some(user)) => println("Success")
case Success(None) => println("User not found")
```

However note that onComplete is much like registering a callback. What you probably want to do is to map the result of your query and turn it into a Boolean indicating a successful login or failed login. A third case would be an exception by the service (eg. database not available).

The simplest way to do that would be to map over the `Future[Option[User]]` (query, in your case) and check if the user was found in the database. That will result in a `Future[Boolean]`:

```
query.map(_.isDefined)
```

Comment: This makes sense, I used Some but didnt thought of using the second case, was very close :). But I still have few questions, how do I retrieve the user related values, like email, userid, etc? And if you mean a boolean, then should I change the return type of DAO method to Future[Boolean]? And, related to my last question, I couldnt understand this query.map(_.isDefined), where should it be used?

Comment: Maybe this question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913074/can-i-do-async-form-validation-in-play-framework-2-x-scala